# i want to access ime "go" btn from android keyboard

Tags: android, webview

I am developing native+hybrid application,

I have Login page loaded in webview,as the user fill the information like uname and password and i want to access the go btn click.

I have tried this document but is [about](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html) android edittext.

user click on go button web service call and further operation that i will easily handle.

how can i do that.

Any help will appreciated..!!

Thank you.

Comment: From a normal app, you would set an OnEditActionListener, and it would call the listener when the go button is pressed.  From an edit field in a webview I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

[OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)

Xml:

```
          <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
```

**java**

```
edit.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                //webservicebtnclick.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```